# ¿Tendrían sentido las preguntas de "Referencia" en Stack Overflow en español? ¿Existe algún caso?

Tags: discusión, respuesta-canónica

En el sitio en inglés existen varias preguntas como esta: *[Reference — What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/5587982)*, por lo que se aprecia suelen tener una muy buena acogida.

¿Tendrían sentido de este lado?

¿Existe ya alguna?

¿Hay normas para este tipo de preguntas? (por ejemplo, a mi juicio, deberían ser marcadas como Wiki de comunidad; deberían empezar por la palabra `Referencia –`).

Comment: Veamos que dicen.. pero para mi es como una gran pregunta canonica dentro de las canonicas.. el tema es que no somos tantos como para mantener eso al dia... alla son muchos mas... pero por lo menos, a mi, la idea no me desagrada...

Comment: No tener nada es peor que tener algo, y lo mejor es que se puede ir actualizando como lo hicieron ellos.

Answer (score 3):

La pregunta incluída como ejemplo es de hace 10 años. Mas recientemente en Meta SO (en el 2016) se publicó una pregunta de cierto modo similar a esta haciendo referencia a la misma pregunta [Error reference collections - Bane or Boon?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314618/1595451)

En síntesis, la pregunta referida no debería ser tomada como ejemplo pues no cumple con las guías de uso del sitio, tanto allá como acá.

Punto y aparte de lo anterior, la iniciativa es muy buena, sólo que en lugar de implementarse en el sitio principal debería implementarse usando otra herramienta, quizás un repositorio en GitHub o una herramienta similar que sea familiar a los expertos de la "etiqueta" (lenguaje de programación, plataforma, IDE, etc).

Quizás podría tomarse "prestado" parte del código usado en traducir.win u otras aplicaciones que de forma similar usan las credenciales de SE para el inicio de sesión de los participantes.

Por otro lado, como en seguramente ocurre en otros sitios de SE, aquí también podríamos tener casos de exepción pero cada uno de estos debe discutirse en específico al menos entre entre 4-6 usuarios habilituales de SO en Español, preferentemente que participen de forma habitual en la "etiqueta" que corresponda al tema de la exepción (lenguage, plataforma, IDE, etc.) incluyendo al menos a un moderador diamantado.

Relacionado

- [The “What does this symbol mean in PHP” reference is a mess](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338070/1595451)

Comment: Interesante lo que comentas. Si por un momento nos abstraemos de las guías del sitio, ¿cuál sería la parte mala de permitir una pregunta así? Es decir, ¿crees que se podría mantener útil y actualizada?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Acabo de agregar una pregunta relacionada que habla de eso

Comment: En lo personal, dejando de lado las referencias y guías, encuentro nada amigable el modelo del sitio para manejar listas de cosas en una pregunta, me parece mejor tener una etiqueta y que haya una pregunta para cada cosa.

Comment: Ajá, conocía esa discusión en Meta. Sin embargo, allí también hablan con mucho aprecio de otra canónica que sí se da como buena: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Pues ni tanto aprecio... la pregunta sólo tiene +52 :) (ya quisiera yo tener preguntas con ese score)

Comment: Lleva seis años bloqueada, luego no puede votarse :D De hecho, si [su línea de tiempo](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22937618/timeline) no me confunde, sacó la friolera de +52 entre las 12.50 que se publicó y las 18.46 que se bloqueó. Es decir, +52 en seis horas :O

Comment: Es interesante la discusión asociada a ese hilo -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate. Yo creo que sería más productivo hablar de casos específicos y lo primero sería ver que haya un número suficiente de intersados en ese caso específico

Comment: ¿Cuando hablás de implementar una herramienta diferente, no te estás refiriendo a algo como Documentation (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354217/14509585), que fue un fracaso rotundo?

Comment: @Pollo ¿Ya tienes un tema y "secuaces" en mente?

Comment: @Pollo Considera tema como título tentativo de la "pregunta"  Por tu respuesta me parece que no.

Comment: @Rubén jajajaja, claro a eso iba, quizás fui yo el que me expresé mal... Acuerdo en que *idealmente* sería genial, pero estoy más inclinado a pensar que es más bien utópico. La intención es buenísima, pero el producto final tengo mis dudas de que pueda llegar a ser algo positivo.

Comment: Yo sí creo que 4 - 6 miembros de la comunidad se podrian poner de acuerdo y crear un diamante pero dudo mucho que llegue a volverse masivo...la herramienta que decidan esos 4 - 6 seguamente será buena.

Comment: @Rubén te juro que deseo estar equivocado y que tengas razón con esto

Comment: @Pollo ¿por qué defines Documentation como fracaso rotundo?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' por ser un proyecto al que le dedicaron muchísimos recursos, en el cual lograron una alta participación, y que se haya dado de baja por no poder estar a la altura del esfuerzo que requiere mantenerlo... Deben ser muchísimas horas totales dedicadas, para lograr la nada misma.

Comment: @Pollo sí, efectivamente le dedicaron muchos recursos y se fueron quemando poco a poco hasta que finalmente lo lanzaron a la papelera. Yo creo que tenía muchas cosas muy positivas, pero faltó paciencia de la empresa y capacidad de enderezarlo ([si bien se intentó](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349410/1983854)). En Codidact han resuelto este problema creando las "categorías", estructuras paralelas a la sección de Q&A donde por ejemplo pueden publicarse artículos ([ejemplo](https://languages.codidact.com/categories/40)) que hacen función de documentación.

Answer (score 2):

A mí me parece una idea excelente. Actualmente se intenta hacer este trabajo en las wiki de las etiquetas correspondientes, pero si somos sinceros con nosotros mismos debemos saber que nadie las lee, por lo que es una tarea bastante inútil.

Por tanto, disponer de esta información en una pregunta parece la mejor manera de indexar información.

Dicho lo cual, creo importante que haya un mínimo de personas editándola y que se coordinen bien en cuanto a criterios y formatos. Que sea de lectura ágil y no haya demasiada información.

Cuenten conmigo para hacer algo similar en el ámbito de Bash y el de Python.

Answer (score 2):

Sería muy práctico tener un compendio de respuestas frecuentes. En mi opinión sirven para un objetivo en particular: ser el destino a donde marcar como duplicadas muchas de las preguntas que no muestran esfuerzo o están en un gris entre poder ponerlas en pausa o no, y que consultan sobre sintaxis básica de un lenguaje.

Pero -sí, venía un "pero"- estoy completamente en contra de implementarlas en esta etapa del sitio. ¿Por qué? Porque me parece que falta mucho para llegar a eso. Antes de tener un compendio, creo que es necesario tener la suficiente cantidad de preguntas canónicas para formar ese compendio. Me parece que no existe aún en el sitio (quizás haya alguna temática en particular que sí, pero mi impresión es que en la gran mayoría no sucede). Y no es sólo un tema de cantidad, sino de contar para cada punto a cubrir una pregunta que ***indiscutiblemente*** sea la aceptada por toda la comunidad.

Empezar a generar compendios a esta altura me parece mucho más problemático. ¿Qué criterio se va a usar para incluir una u otra pregunta? Seguramente como usuario de hace mucho tiempo en el sitio, tengas opiniones formadas de cómo se debe responder a un tema, pero te aseguro que no todos van a acordar con vos. Quizás te guste redactar respuestas kilométricas, que cubren todos y cada uno de los aspectos de un tema, pero quizás a otros les guste más las respuestas breves y que van al grano. ¿Quién define entonces cuál va a ser la pregunta que quede marcada en este compendio? No creo que le corresponda a nadie en particular. Al contrario, creo que hay que dejarlo librado a la voluntad de todos los que voten (y que evolucionen en el tiempo). Estoy convencido de que pensar en que 1 usuario empiece a definir hoy cuál es la canónica a publicar sería el principio de varios discordios.

No digo que se genere una guerra de ediciones por esto, pero sí creo que daría lugar a que muchos estén en desacuerdo y no hagan nada al respecto.

No obstante, sí me parece un buen objetivo a futuro. Es decir, pensemos en primero empezar a generar el contenido para que haya suficiente cantidad de canónicas como para que valga la pena indexarlas... A futuro, cuando ya estén más establecidas.

Comment: Discrepo con el optimismo: creo actualmente hay menos vocación que antes. Mucha gente ya dejó el sitio y nunca se acabaron de definir bien todas estas cosas, por lo que ahora es algo así como un reino de taifas sin mayor control (a los moderadores los veo haciendo funciones de usuario 10 K pero poco control y gestión de estas situaciones).

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' de la mayoría de las cosas que mencionás, no tenía la menor idea, pero tomo tu palabra (confío mucho en tu criterio -basado en lo que leí de tus publicaciones)... Lo que sí, no estoy siendo **nada optimista**. Estoy elegantemente diciendo que no ("no hasta que suceda esto otro", pero "no" al fin)... Más aún, si es así como decís, con más argumentos todavía: "*Busquemos lo que está mal en el sitio que haya hecho que se fueran/desganen otros usuarios!!!!*" (-no hablo del problema con Monica, sino de cualquier otra cosa que no esté bien y que se pueda arreglar)

Comment: Me recuerdas tantiiiismo a un paisano tuyo que también tenía contribuciones y análisis excelentes...